# When a scheme is consisted of closed points and generic points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I'd like to know when a scheme is consisted of closed points and generic points.

For example, if $X$ is an integral separated scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$ with generic point $\eta$, then any point $p$ in $X-\eta$ is closed?

If $X$ is as above, then I think $p$ is closed iff $p$ is closed in some open affine neighborhood $\text{Spec} A$ of $p$, so it suffices to prove that any non-minimal prime ideal in $A$ is maximal. This is equivalent to $\dim A=1$. But I don't think $\dim A=1$ is true...

A scheme $X$ satisfying the above conditions is called a variety on page 105 of Hartshorne, but I always have the feeling that schemes are generalized of varieties by adding generic points, that is if $X$ is an integral separated scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$ scheme, then by deleting all its closed points we can get the unique generic point. But I can't see why such a scheme is consisted of closed points and generic points... Where I am wrong?

By the way, in Hartshorne's definition, separatedness means $X\rightarrow X\times_kX$ is closed embedding or $X\rightarrow X\times_{\mathbb{Z}}X$ is closed embedding? I am not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider the spectrum of $k[X,Y]$, then the prime ideal $X$ gives a point whose closure is the locus where $X=0$, i.e., the $Y$-axis

Comment: Just separated usually means that $X$ is separated over $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Z$, but if $X$ is also an $A$-Scheme for some other commutative ring $A$ then $X$ is separated iff it is separated over $\operatorname{Spec} A$. (So in your case $X\to X\times_kX$ is a closed immersion iff $X\to X\times_{\Bbb Z} X$ is).

Comment: You are correct in saying that you "add generic points" to a variety $X$ to build a scheme, and of course you add a generic point whose closure is $X$, but you also add the generic points of every closed subvariety inside $X$ (as in Pol's example). For an affine variety, this is saying that you add all of the prime ideals, which cut out irreducible subvarieties after you take a ring quotient.

Comment: Thanks very much for all comments！